# Question about PCA: how are PC scores generated using PC eigenvectors?

Tags: pca, matlab

My question is quite elementary but I need help understanding the basic concepts.
In the following example from the Mathworks [documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/princomp.html;jsessionid=7d1614ae9e8aa84acbe93adc16f6)
of the `princomp` function

```
load hald;
[pc,score,latent,tsquare] = princomp(ingredients);
pc,latent
```

we get the following values for:

```
pc =

   -0.0678   -0.6460    0.5673    0.5062
   -0.6785   -0.0200   -0.5440    0.4933
    0.0290    0.7553    0.4036    0.5156
    0.7309   -0.1085   -0.4684    0.4844

latent =

  517.7969
   67.4964
   12.4054
    0.2372

score =

   36.8218   -6.8709   -4.5909    0.3967
   29.6073    4.6109   -2.2476   -0.3958
  -12.9818   -4.2049    0.9022   -1.1261
   23.7147   -6.6341    1.8547   -0.3786
   -0.5532   -4.4617   -6.0874    0.1424
  -10.8125   -3.6466    0.9130   -0.1350
  -32.5882    8.9798   -1.6063    0.0818
   22.6064   10.7259    3.2365    0.3243
   -9.2626    8.9854   -0.0169   -0.5437
   -3.2840  -14.1573    7.0465    0.3405
    9.2200   12.3861    3.4283    0.4352
  -25.5849   -2.7817   -0.3867    0.4468
  -26.9032   -2.9310   -2.4455    0.4116
```

Legend:

**latent** is a vector containing the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of X.

**pc** is a p-by-p matrix, each column containing coefficients for one principal component. The columns are in order of decreasing component variance.**

**score** is the principal component scores; that is, the representation of X in the principal component space. Rows of SCORE correspond to observations, columns to components.

**Can somebody explain whether the values of score are genetrated somehow using the values of pc and if this true, what kind of computation is perfomed ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the story [here](http://matlabdatamining.blogspot.it/2010/02/principal-components-analysis.html), or a deeper introduction to PCA, with explanatory code in Matlab, in Jonathon Shlens, [A Tutorial on Principal Component Analysis](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.1100v1.pdf).

In brief, SCORE = X * pc, where X is your centered (or standardized) data matrix.

Comment: This is the correct answer but you could be a lot more detailed. It wouldn't harm giving the one-liner code for example (`scores = (ingredients - repmat(mean(ingredients),size(ingredients,1),1)) * pc`) or explain the concept of projecting the data in a new coordinate system defined by the PCs.

Comment: Sure, but I don't speak matlab ;-)

Comment: Fair enough on M-code, but that was only part of my suggestion though. :) And it was the least important one actually. Providing self-contained answers is important, as there is link-rot; if the link you provide goes bad your answers just lost all its background.